# Bootstrap for typescript(electron)

Tags: typescript, twitter-bootstrap, electron

i was trying to work with bootstrap in electron but however it didnt work.

i installed package of bootstrap and react-bootstrap but it's giving me this error
do i have to install different type of package for electron instead of react?

this is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import Community from './component/contents/Community/Community';
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Community></Community>
      <Button></Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and the error is this.

[image]